# Where to put interstitial ad and banner ad using new admob

Tags: android, android-activity, admob, google-play

Play Store and Admob is updated after March 2014. My applications are suspended by playstore because of ad-policy violation.

Mailed me this

Ad Walls and Interstitial Ads
Interstitial ads may only be displayed inside of the app they came with. Forcing the user to click on ads or submit personal information for advertising purposes in order to fully use an app is prohibited. A prominent and accessible target must be made available to users in any interstitial ad so they may dismiss the ad without penalty or inadvertent click-through.

for eg. My app contains two activity 
1. DashboardActivity.
2. MainActivity.

BannerAd:
I have place BannerAd in both the activity in respective layout file (xml).

InterstitialAd:
I have place InterstitialAd in both the acitvity. When activity loads the InterstitialAd will be open and when you get out of activity onBackPressed() method I again load InterstitialAd.
i.e. Total 4 times it load in the whole application. This was working with legacy admob.

Please tell me where to put banner and interstitial ad if anyone updated there application with new admob.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying an interstitial on Activity start and end has always been frowned upon by Admob.

What you should do is to *load* your interstitial on Activity start and then at a natural break point in your app (*not* at Activity end) display the interstitial. A good example is when a user completes a level in a game or after performing some function for the user.